# Form is not displaying errors if ajax is used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm checking this form for errors using PHP code which is on the same `index.php` file:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">

                        <?php if(!empty($formErrors)){  ?>
                            <div id="errors">    
                                <?php 
                                    foreach($formErrors as $error)
                                        { echo '* ' . $error . '.<br/>';}
                                ?>
                            </div>
                       <?php } ?>

<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

The PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

         $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
         $formErrors = array();

            if(strlen($fname) < 2 ){
                $formErrors[] = "First name must be longer than 1 character";
            }
}
?>
```

Everything is working fine up to this point, except that I want to prevent the page from scrolling to the top upon form submission. Therefore i used ajax to solve this problem:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: $(this).attr("method"),
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: $(this).serialize()
    });
  });
```

Now the form errors won't display anymore, which is not what I want. How can I show the errors again while not discarding ajax? Thanks.

Comment: You need to write some JavaScript to read the errors data from php (which will need to echo the errors data as JSON), and then put the errors into the page in the right place

Comment: Your php is written as if the form will submit using default form submission , not ajax

Comment: I used this ajax code just to prevent the scroll issue, that's all i need besides displaying errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this isn't the best way, you can echo the JSON from the file and display those errors in your ajax function like below:

**FrontEnd(ajax):**

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: $(this).attr("method"),
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: $(this).serialize() + '&ajax=1',
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(res){
        if(res.success === false){
           $('#errors').html('<ul><li>' + res.errors.join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>');
        }else{
           $('#errors').html('');   
        }
      } 
    });
  });
```

**Backend:**

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

         $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
         $formErrors = array();

            if(strlen($fname) < 2 ){
                $formErrors[] = "First name must be longer than 1 character";
            }
        // add this additional check 
        if(($_POST['ajax'] ?? 'N/A') == '1'){
            echo json_encode(['success' => false,'errors' => $formErrors]);
            exit; // since we will only send the JSON back to the browser, not the entire form
        } 
}
?>
```

Change your form code to this(adding a `errors` div always by default):

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <div id="errors"></div>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: It's working now,  but the empty div itself is always displayed so i'll try to figure out a way to hide it until errors occur, thanks a lot for your effort and time.

Comment: @MrShabana That's great. You can toggle with it's visibility in the if-else conditions in ajax and make it hidden by default.